# Error in SQL Oracle - ORA-00923FROM keyword not found where expected error in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i confront with unexpected 'from' error and cant handle it- in line 6

```
    SELECT
    G.StudentID,
    G.ExamID,
    G.Grade,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY G.StudentID ORDER BY E.ExamDate DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM Grades_tsk G
    JOIN Exams_tsk E ON G.ExamID = E.ExamID
```

Gives error like:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: ROWNUM is a reserved Word in oracle, you can't use it with out double quotes

Answer (score 0):

`ROWNUM` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html#GUID-55C49D1E-BE08-4C50-A9DD-8593EB925612) and cannot be used as an (unquoted) identifier.

Use a different identifier, such as `rn`:

```sql
SELECT G.StudentID,
       G.ExamID,
       G.Grade,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY G.StudentID ORDER BY E.ExamDate DESC) AS rn
FROM   Grades_tsk G
       JOIN Exams_tsk E
       ON G.ExamID = E.ExamID
```

Comment: omg, thanks so much, I can't believe that I made such a careless mistake